# Make [hardware-selection] a synonym of [hardware-rec]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

All [hardware-selection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-selection) questions are actually [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec). It's only 6 questions, but [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec) has just 192, so [hardware-selection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-selection) makes 3% of the total - I think it's popular enough to be synonymized rather than deleted.

Comment: Wait, isn't hardware/software recommendation OT in first place? Why would we have a tag?

Comment: @Braiam it was discussed before both for [hardware-rec](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2991/194694) and for [software-rec](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6434/194694). My personal opinion is that we should [get rid of them](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7032/194694), but for now they are there and we just have to deal with it.

Comment: Well, that's some mixed signals you are sending to users. While for one side there's the help page/FAQ (that nobody reads) that says that soft/hw rec is off-topic, you have a tag (that they read and see) that if there are also other questions like that then they can ask. This is *elemental my dear Watson*, tags tell people what is on-topic to people. If you have the tags, people assumes that you allow those kind of questions.