# Are the policies on product recommendations from 2011 and 2012 still good for 2015?

Tags: support, scope

I noticed both the [software rec](https://superuser.com/tags/software-rec/info) and [hardware rec](https://superuser.com/tags/hardware-rec/info) tags exist and that they reference these two meta posts:

- [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372) (2012)
- [What is the difference between shopping recommendations and hardware-rec tagged questions?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2991) (2011)

Are the views from those threads and information in the tags on how to ask a good version of those questions congruent with current standards?